# js stop click function subsequent execution after call back in ajax of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On the first click `myClick()` has been called again in itself of `myLoad()` then at the second click, this `myClick()` will execute two times

*=> The following causes two subsequent execution of
click event of `#myBtn` by one click*

How to avoid or stop this? Please anybody suggest me new logical method or which way to stop this.

```js
$(function() {
  myLoad()
})

function myClick() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    myLoad(); //load new every click
  });
}

function myLoad() {
  $("#myCnt").load('ajax.php', {
    "data": "some"
  }, function() {
    myClick() //to live the click event works after ajax load
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is that in each call to `myClick()` an new event handler is attached to button.

You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off) to remove existing event handler attached using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

```
function myClick(){
  $("#myBtn").off('click').on('click', function(){
    myLoad();//load new every click
  });
}
```

---

A better approach would be to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

A good read [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

*Modify you code as*

```js
$(function() {
  myLoad();

  $(document).on("click", "#myBtn", function() {
    myLoad(); //load new every click
  });

})

function myLoad() {
  $("#myCnt").load('ajax.php', { "data": "some"}, function() {
    //No need to call my click
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues is in the flow of your code

First time when you call `myClick()` it binds the click event with `#myBtn`,

On second time it binds that event again , so it will be called twice , remove that event binding from there,

Or else  `$("#myBtn").click` will be bind each time you call the myClick function.

---

As solution please try this code :

```
$(function(){
  myLoad()
})

$("body").on( "click" , "#myBtn" , function(){
    myLoad();//load new every click
});

function myLoad(){
  $("#myCnt").load('ajax.php', {"data":"some"}, function(){
    $("#myBtn").trigger("click");
  })
}
```